# How to initialise Magento Requisition over AJAX?

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, magento2.4.3

I have tried several ways to initialize Magento RequisitionList after AJAX call.

First I tried with **data-mage-init**
Please correct me if there is anything wrong.

[image]

I have used the underscore JS template to generate the HTML
[image]

Here is the HTML DOM after AJAX call

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much time spent found the solution. Attached below.

The HTML render using **x-magento-init**

```
<div class="block block-requisition-list social-button requisition_list"
 data-bind="scope: 'requisition_<%=item.id%>'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "requisition_<%=item.id%>": {
                    "component": "Magento_RequisitionList/js/requisition/action/product/add",
                    "editModuleName": "requisition_<%=item.id%>.edit",
                    "title": "Add to Requisition List",
                    "action": "http://magento.local/requisition_list/item/add/",
                    "sku": "<%=item.sku%>",
                    "productFormSelector":"form[data-product-sku=\"<%=item.sku%>\"]"
                },
                "requisition_<%=item.id%>.edit": {
                    "component": "Magento_RequisitionList/js/requisition/list/edit",
                    "modal": "add_to_requisition_popup",
                    "saveUrl": "http://magento.local/rest/V1/requisition_lists/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
ko.cleanNode($('.requisition_list')[0]);
var nodeCtx = ko.contextFor($('.requisition_list')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(nodeCtx, $('.requisition_list')[0]);
```

[image]

Thanks :)